# SQL CAST(int as varchar) throws error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Good evening,

I'm trying to convert an int to a varchar using the CAST() function but it gives me the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected VARCHAR
```

and this is the code

```
CAST(p2v as varchar)
```

and i also tried

```
CAST(p2v as varchar(MAX))
```

I got the same problem when i try using CONVERT()

Answer (score 9):

It must be `char`, not `varchar`

> The type for the result can be one of the following values:
>
> - BINARY[(N)]
> - **CHAR[(N)]**
> - DATE
> - DATETIME
> - DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
> - SIGNED [INTEGER]
> - TIME
> - UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: It solved the problem with the error, but now I only get a 'null' result.

Comment: What was the integer being cast?